# Set column type : categorized in a Domino view via java via NCSO.jar

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to make a view in a database via Java that has a column that is both sorted and categorized.

I have figured out how to make a view, and how to make a column that is sorted:

> db.createView("ViewName", "").createColumn(1, "Form","Form").setSorted(true);

I need it to also to be categorized. In the java API for note (*NCSO.jar*) there is a method like:

> db.getView("ViewName").getColumn(1).isCategory();

I need the opposite of that, like : `.setCategorized(true);`

Hope somebody can help me.

Ps: in the gui you do it via this panel, under Type:
[GUI part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0FNI.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an oversight of the API.  I've never seen a way to set a view column to be categorized.

It is awkward, but you might have success using the copyColumn() method.  In this case you'd need a dummy view, with a single categorized column, that you use as a template.  Then call createView() with a templateView parameter.  Then you could either just change the properties of that categorized column, or copy it if you need more than one categorized column.

Comment: I was affright it would be something like that. How can it be an oversight, as the NCSO.jar has been out there since the coming of ages (or at least since v.7). But thanks for the confirmation of the bad news:)